# How do I get my elements inline in the top left corner?

Tags: html, css

Element 2 is an image for the youtube logo. Element 1 is a button with a visual hover effect with three bars stacked on top of each other.
I want the button on the left and the image right next to it.
I need them in the upper left corner.

Here is a screenshot so far https://postimg.cc/Mn2B8wCR

Here is the code I have so far

```css
.element1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
}

.element2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hamburger {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #636363;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hamburger>div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 5px;
}

.first {
  width: 55px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 20px;
}

.second {
  width: 40px;
  top: 45px;
  left: 20px;
}

.third {
  width: 50px;
  top: 65px;
  left: 20px;
}

.hamburger:hover div {
  width: 60px;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="element1">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second"></div>
      <div class="third"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="element2">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Logo_of_YouTube_%282015-2017%29.svg" alt="Youtube logo" class="logo">
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap element 1 and element 2 with display inline block

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a `container` and use `display: flex;`.

```css
.nav-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.element1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;

}

.wrapper{
  padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hamburger{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #636363;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.hamburger > div{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 5px;
}
.first{
    width: 55px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 20px;
}
.second{
    width: 40px;
    top: 45px;
    left: 20px;
}
.third{
    width: 50px;
    top: 65px;
    left: 20px;

}
.hamburger:hover div{
    width: 60px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

.element2{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <div class="element1">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <div class="first"></div>
                <div class="second"></div>
                <div class="third"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Logo_of_YouTube_%282015-2017%29.svg" alt="Youtube logo" class="logo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, wrap all of element 1 and 2 with a 'container' div:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="element1">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="hamburger">
              <div class="first"></div>
              <div class="second"></div>
              <div class="third"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="element2">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Logo_of_YouTube_%282015-2017%29.svg" alt="Youtube logo" class="logo">
  </div>

</div>
```

In CSS, make div container flex and into a row.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Change your positions of your hamburger and wrapper class:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hamburger{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #636363;
    border-radius: 5px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```css
.container {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:auto }
```

/* the margin right auto is to force the elements to be on the left corner */ps it should be only the imge and the button inside this div(class='container')

Answer (score -1):

Is this you want to do?

**Edit:**

Here I done below changes:

- Removed all styles of the `.wrapper` which don't need there
- Added `vertical-align: middle` for `.element1 and .element2`
- Removed `width` from `.element1` which don't need there
- Added `margin-left` to `.element2` for space

```css
.element1{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
.element2{
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
.hamburger{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #636363;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.hamburger > div{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 5px;
}
.first{
    width: 55px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 20px;
}
.second{
    width: 40px;
    top: 45px;
    left: 20px;
}
.third{
    width: 50px;
    top: 65px;
    left: 20px;
}
.hamburger:hover div {
    width: 60px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.logo {
    width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="element1">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hamburger">
            <div class="first"></div>
            <div class="second"></div>
            <div class="third"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="element2">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Logo_of_YouTube_%282015-2017%29.svg" alt="Youtube logo" class="logo">
</div>
```

Comment: So you want OP and others interested to make a code diff to find out what you changed?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add the changes which I made in this code. This will not happen again. And thanks for your comment. Let me do this.